# .remove() in table row leaves field with null values on submit

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, forms, form-submit

I have a table with several rows. Rows are dynamically created and removed from javascript. So remove button does.

```
    $("#TaskTableBody").on('click','.removeSchedule',function(){
        $(this).closest("tr").remove();
    });
```

So i have a submit button that i use to redirect the object of the form to validation on server.

The problem is that when i delete rows ui works properly but the object that is sent to validation has all the removed rows with null values.

```
$("#validatePlan").click(function(e){

    e.preventDefault();
    var ScheduleForm=$("#form2").serializeArray();       
    sessionStorage.setItem("schedForm",JSON.stringify(ScheduleForm));   
    sessionStorage.setItem("flag","set");

    $("#form2").attr('action',"/TaskSchedulePlanValidation/");
    $("#form2").submit();
});
```

i am storing the form to sessionStorage in order to reload it after validation. Reloading works properly and does not show rows with null values that where previously removed, but the submit object still has these rows.

The html part is:

```
<form th:action="@{/saveSchedule/}" th:object="${plan}" id="form2" method="post">   
    <div >
        <div >
            <h3 class="plan-header"> Schedule Table</h3>
            <button type="submit" th:formaction="@{/TaskSchedulePlanValidation/" form="form2" id="validatePlan">
            <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-list-alt"> Validate Plan</span> 
            </button>                       
        </div>
        <div id="planDiv">
            <table id="planTable" class="pre-scrollable">
                <thead>
                    <tr>
                        <th>Planned Date</th>
                        <th>Planned Quantity</th>
                        <th><button type="button" class="btn btn-success btn-circle-sm" id="addRow"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-plus"></span></button></th>
                        <th>Completed Quantity</th>

                    </tr>
                </thead>
                <tbody id="scheduledTaskTableBody">
                    <tr th:each="schedule, iter : ${TaskPlan.ScheduleList}">
                        <td class="ScheduledPlannedDate"><input type="text" class="datepickerSchedule ScheduledPlannedDateInput" th:name="ScheduleList[__${iter.index}__].plannedDate" th:value="${schedule.plannedDate}"></td>
                        <td class="ScheduledQty"><input type="number" class="ScheduledTaskQtyInput" th:name="ScheduleList[__${iter.index}__].plannedQty" min="0" step="0.1" th:value="${#numbers.formatDecimal(schedule.plannedQty,1,'COMMA',1,'POINT')}"></td>
                        <td><button type="button" class="removeSchedule btn btn-danger btn-circle-sm"><span class=" glyphicon glyphicon-remove"></span></button></td>
                        <td class="ScheduledCompletedQuantity"><input type="number" class="scheduledTaskInput ScheduledTaskCompletedQuantity ScheduledTaskCompletedQtyInput" th:name="ScheduleList[__${iter.index}__].completedQty" min="0" step="0.1" th:value="${#numbers.formatDecimal(schedule.completedQty,1,1,'POINT')}"></td>                    
                    </tr>
                </tbody>
            </table>
        </div>
        <div class="submitClearButtonsForm2Div">
            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-success" id="SubmitScheduleDistButton" form="form2"><i>Submit</i></button>
            <button type="reset" class="btn btn-danger" id="ClearScheduleDistButton" form="form2"><i>Clear</i></button>
        </div>
    </div>      
</form>
```

i can say that form.serialiseArray() gives the proper list of rows but normal submit has everything (i mean deleted rows , and the objects inside that rows are set to null)

Comment: What does your HTML look like?

Comment: i have added the html part